# cuda blur with array

Tags: cuda

I am new to image processing and want to make blur based on each pixel blur value .There is an integer array which holds blur value for each pixel and using threadid in global function , I want to change that pixels value for blur.My image format is  Format24bppRgb and the problem when I want to update pixel value , I can't load an integer value to that pixel.  I really didn't understand the structure and don't know if it is possible changing pixel with directly int values not changing Color.red Color.blue ..value. Should I convert Format24bppRgb format to any other image for this?  Here my code :

```
__global__ void Workload(Format24bppRgb* imageData, int imageWidth, int *PixelBlurAmount)
 {
int tidX = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int tidY = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

int tid  = tidX + tidY * imageWidth; 

imageData[tid] = PixelBlurAmount[tid];
 }
```

and main function :

```
       int pixelBlurValue[1024*1024];

   for(int i=0; i<8; i++) 
   {
       for(int j=0; j<(1024*1024/8); j++) 
       { 
           pixelBlurValue[i*j]=i;  // VALUE
       }
   }       

   int * dev_pixValue;
   cudaMalloc(&dev_pixValue,sizeof(int)* (1024*1024));  
   cudaMemcpy(dev_pixValue,pixelBlurValue,sizeof(int) * (1024*1024)    ,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   Workload<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(
   dev_ptr_imageData,  
   imageWidth,
   dev_pixValue);
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: What is your question? You have not explained in any detail what exactly it is you want to do or are having trouble with, and the code you have posted only shows what amounts to a `memcpy` kernel. Please edit your question to more clearly explain what it is you are trying to do and what you want to know. There are many knowledgeable and helpful people on Stack Overflow, but they can't read minds....

Comment: Sorry for short explanation. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Where is the definition of `Format24bppRgb`?

Answer (score 1):

There is some sample code inside the CUDA SDK that you have probably installed, please check. For the theoretical part, it is based on [this technical note](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_64_website/projects/convolutionSeparable/doc/convolutionSeparable.pdf). Note that most blurs are actually separable kernels, hence there are already some fast algorithms for the convolution (that can be adapted to CUDA).

Comment: Thank you . I tried this way and used a mean filter. But I want to make that each pixel should know what is their blur value (according to mean filter all are 1)  and directly giving each pixel to that value for blur. I don't want to use filter array . Is it possible to give an integer value to a pixel ?